# R: Find index of Matrix with smallest value

Tags: r

Given matrix

```
x <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow=2, ncol=2)
colnames(x) <- c('a','b')
rownames(x) <- c('c','d')
```

How do I find the column index/name and row index/name of the minimum value?

I've tried which.min, but I need to get the row/column index rather than the element. Any ideas?

Comment: I imagine that you mean `colnames(x)<-c('a','b','c','d')`?

Comment: oh man, i couldn't find that question on google, maybe wording...we can close it if you want

Answer (score 20):

You can use `which`

```
which(x == min(x), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

For example :

```
x <- matrix(c(1, 2, 0, 4), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
which(x == min(x), arr.ind = TRUE)
##      row col
## [1,]   1   2
```

Comment: +1 -- `arrayInd(which.min(x), dim(x))` should be faster (`x == min(x)` is expensive). It will always return the first minimum while yours will return all of them.

Comment: @flodel, I've been using R for almost a decade and this is the first I've seen that shortcut to give `which.min` the `arr.ind` functionality, *efficiently*, without the "cost" and floating-point "risk" of `x == min(x)`. Awesome! Learning something new every day. (The fact that it is closely included in `?which` is a little embarrassing ...)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to treat the matrix like a vector you can use `which.min`

```
which.min(x)
# > [1] 1
which.max(x)
# > [1] 4
```

Being the first and 4th element.

You can also find the max and return an ordered vector w/ the position (but not the min)

```
max.col(x)
# [1] 2 2
```

Comment: well, then do `max.col(-x)`. But that gives the location of the minimum *for each row*, not what the OP is after.